# Using main style.css with add_editor_style

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg, add-editor-style

All the resources I've read online suggest using a different CSS file (i.e. `editor-style.css`) in order to style the WYSIWYG editor to better resemble what the actual content will look like.

For the purpose of testing I tried to just use the main `style.css` file that I've been using for the rest of the site and the styling in the WYSIWYG editor looks great and so far I haven't noticed any problems by doing this.

Should I still create a new `editor-style.css` and use that or is it an acceptable practice to use my main `style.css`?

For reference, this is the code I used below:

```
function wysiwyg_styles() {
    add_editor_style( 'style.css' );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wysiwyg_styles' );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is: you can use whatever stylesheet you want for the editor. `editor-style.css` is just the default stylesheet loaded if none is passed to `add_editor_style()`.

This will load the specified stylesheet:

```
add_editor_style( 'some-stylsheet.css' );
```

This will load editor-style.css:

```
add_editor_style();
```

Use whatever better fits your needs.

By the way, it is better practice to add the editor stylesheet using `after_setup_theme` action, not `init`, as it is something specific for the theme:

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'cyb_theme_setup' );
fucntion cyb_theme_setup() {
    add_editor_style();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The editor doesn't use the every style used by your website's front end. So, you don't need the whole `style.css` file. But still, the file is cached by the browser, so there won't be a problem of performance, probably.

But there might be a conflict problem if you `style.css` is fairly huge. It might override the other styles used by the admin panel. You might have noticed a few small changes in the overall look of your dashboard ( Probably, not certainly ). In this case, you can write a small stylesheet and only include styles that are used in the single posts and pages.

Answer (score -1):

There's no reason you can't do that, but you need to consider a couple of things:

Firstly, you're loading a *lot* of styles that are irrelevant to the content represented by the editor.

And the other thing to consider is that the TinyMCE content isn't wrapped in an `entry` class or similar, so the front-end of your theme would need to use the base `h1`,`p`,`ul` styles etc. without any extra specificity or the content in the editor won't actually match the front-end. I deliberately build my themes so that the content represented by the editor uses the base styles for this very reason.

I also use LESS when developing my themes, so I break out various parts of the CSS into separate files like `base.less`, `entry.less`, `widget.less`. Then I have two main LESS files for the front-end and editor that just import the bits they need. So `style.less` might look like:

```
@import (reference) 'variables';
@import 'base/normalize';
@import 'base/html';
@import 'base/forms';
@import 'base/media';
@import 'components/grid';
@import 'components/header'
@import 'components/sidebar';
@import 'components/navbar';
@import 'components/footer';
```

While `editor-style.less` looks like:

```
@import (reference) 'variables';
@import 'base/normalize';
@import 'base/html';
@import 'base/forms';
@import 'base/media';
```

Then `style.less` gets compiled into `style.css` and `editor-style.less` gets compiled into `editor-style.css`.

So I'm only writing one set of styles, but only the bits I need get put into the edtior stylesheet.